# Any way to print the task graph before Gradle actually performs the task?

Tags: gradle, task

Not exactly a newb but am trying to dig a big deeper and understand a bit better ... just thought it might be a nice idea to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interface [`TaskExecutionGraph`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionGraph.html) provides [`getAllTasks`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionGraph.html#getAllTasks--) method which (from the docs):

> Returns the tasks which are included in the execution plan. The tasks are returned in the order that they will be executed.

It seems that the output of this method might be used to print the task graph.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Opal I did this:

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {taskGraph ->
    println "Tasks"
    taskGraph.getAllTasks().eachWithIndex{ task, n ->
        println "${n + 1} $task"
        task.dependsOn.eachWithIndex{ depObj, m ->
            println "  ${ m + 1 } $depObj"
        }
    }
}
```

Output for a Java build:

```
Tasks
1 task ':compileJava'
2 task ':processResources'
3 task ':classes'
  1 compileJava
  2 dirs
  3 processResources
4 task ':jar'
5 task ':assemble'
  1 org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultPublishArtifactSet$ArtifactsTaskDependency@48db7705
6 task ':compileTestJava'
7 task ':processTestResources'
8 task ':testClasses'
  1 processTestResources
  2 dirs
  3 compileTestJava
9 task ':test'
10 task ':check'
  1 value: task ':test'
11 task ':build'
  1 check
  2 assemble
```

For me, as a Gradle neophyte (one up from a newb), this is great! Although it leaves me *slightly* puzzled:

1) "build" depends only on "check" and "assemble", and these have 1 dependency each, each with no dependencies. So how does it know to run all the other tasks (which obviously it has to)... I must be missing something.

2) what is dependency "dirs" and "org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultPublishArtifactSet$ArtifactsTaskDependency@48db7705"? More importantly, where does these actually come from? `getDependsOn()` returns a `Set<Object>` so these may be something other than `Task`s.

Plenty to investigate...

Comment: Maybe late but you can use [task tree plugin](https://github.com/dorongold/gradle-task-tree)
For build it goes: `assemble -> jar -> classes -> compileJava -> processResources`

Answer (score 3):

The [gradle-taskinfo plugin](https://gitlab.com/barfuin/gradle-taskinfo#gradle-taskinfo) probably does just what Opal describes in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57765627/1005481).
I wrote it, so I might be biased, but I use it a lot and it works great for me. 
Maybe it saves you some time coding!